# No shipping options - create order admin panel - Magento

Tags: magento

When I attempt to create an order directly from the Magento admin panel, there are no shipping options available. I always get the message "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."

I have tried altering shipping country, shipping zip code, product weight and product price to get shipping options to appear, but have had no luck.

The 'Free Shipping' option is enabled, and being used on the front-end checkout.

I'm on Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Comment: No Quote means the shipping conditions doesn't match your order ! ex: shipping country ? / weight / etc.. so check the configuration for the shipping methods and check again !

Comment: on System config you can change the config to Shipping, probably there have something about "Can use on admin." don't remember now.

Comment: @Meabed I have tried altering weight, price, zip code and it never works. However the shipping methods appear on the front end for the same user and product, so I don't believe it's a shipping conditions issue.

Comment: @Guerra I haven't seen any shipping settings that have anything like "use on admin". If you remember where it is please let me know.

Comment: So debug the shipping module and see where it exits !

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It causes problems creating orders in the admin panel if under:

System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Settings

not settings are made.

Does this fix it?

Comment: All information has already been entered here (e.g. country, zip code). I have even tried changing it to a different address. No luck